# How to add a seperate layout with date picker dialog?

Tags: android

I have a history button,when I click that my date picker dialog appears but I want it to be like in the picture. How can I add that box on the top of dialog?Please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw8Tr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a [DiaogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). This class allows you to open a dialog with main content being that of the one you set in the xml layout class. In the .xml layout class add the header view that you had along with datepicker widget.

Implementation of a DialogFragment is the same as that of a fragment you just need to extend it. [Here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-dialogfragment-tutorial/) is a basic example from the net.